# Totals in excel without including certain cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This might be a bit difficult to explain, but below is the spreadsheet im using, for the totals highlighted in blue i want to create a formula that shows the difference between the two years but only up to the previous month. For example as we are currently in July, i want to show the difference in the two years from May-June.

Currently i am using the formula;

```
=SUM(K4:K5)-SUM(F4:F5)
```

Which works, but it means i will have to update it every time i add information in for the new months. Is there a formula i can use thats not overly complicated to get the same result, but it will update automatically when i add new information in.

[image: Excel Spreadsheet]

Comment: Is it the percentage calculations in cells `O16`, `S16`, `W16` and `AA16` that are the source of your problem? As far as I can tell, everything else should work just fine if you use `=SUM(H4:H15)` in cell `H16` and similar for all cells in range `I16:AA16` except the percentages. As I'm sure you'll know, Excel treats empty cells as zeroes in the `SUM()` function. If this is your problem, investigate the `OFFSET()` function and have a think about how it can be used in conjunction with the `SUM()` function.

Comment: If i use cell `M16` as my example, my problem is that if i used `=SUM(H4:H15)-SUM(C4:C15)` i would get -823999 as it takes into account months July-April as well from 2015/2016. The only cells i want to take into account are ones when the months on both years both have values, so in this case May and June. Its simple enough using `=SUM(H4:H5)`, however this would mean id have to update the formulas everytime i add in extra information which i don't want to do.

Comment: I agree. However, `=SUM(H4:H15)-SUM(OFFSET(C4,0,0,2,1))` will give you what you want and next month it will be `=SUM(H4:H15)-SUM(OFFSET(C4,0,0,3,1))` and `=SUM(H4:H15)-SUM(OFFSET(C4,0,0,4,1))` the month after - can you see where this is going? If you can - then what can be used for the changing value in the formula? (Hint: think `COUNT`)

Comment: I've been sitting here for a while, and ive just realised for `M16` `Q16` `U16` and `Y16` its simply the total of their columns `=SUM(M4:M15)` as i already have formulas in place to fill in the other rows when new information is entered into the 2016/17 table.

And then for the percentages i used the answer provided by @Mattias which provided me with the correct answers and also updates automatically.

Thanks for your help DMM, i will be having a look into the `OFFSET()` formula as i havent come across this yet and it appears to be quite useful.

Comment: @DMM also in answer to where you were trying to take me, i came up with `=SUM(H4:H15)-SUM(OFFSET(C4,0,0,COUNT(H4:H15),1))`. Would that have been correct as well?

Comment: Also, you are making the formula for `M16` unnecessarily complicated. Presumably, `M4` is `=H4-C4`, `M5` is `=H5-C5` so `=SUM(M4:M15)` will work fine in `M16` irrespective of which month you are in. The only real difficulty lies with the % calculations in `O16`, `S16`, `W16` and `AA16`. the value in `O16` is derivable from `SUM(C4:C5)` and either `H16` or `M16` (as either `=M16/SUM(C4:C5)` or `=H16/SUM(C4:C5)-1)). Next month you'll need `C4:C6` instead of `C4:C5` and `C4:C7` month after that. Read my earlier comments again - the answer to your problems are there.

Comment: Comments crossed in the post - well done, you got there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the =SUMIF() formula.

It will only perform the sum operation if certain conditions are met, so we can set it up to sum all entries in a certain range that are not empty.

Here is a good explanation of the function.
https://exceljet.net/formula/sum-if-not-blank

So for your case, you would write (in the sum cell)

=SUMIF(K4:K15,"<>",K4:K15) - SUMIF(K4:K15,"<>",F4:F15)